# Swift 2 post and response codes to convert useful function

Tags: ios, json, function, post, swift2

I want to send param strings and url to a function and I want to return a JSON success and message string. Please help for the same.

Following is my code:

```
 let postEndpoint:NSString = "http://bla.com/application/login.php?email=\(username)&password=\(password)"


            print(postEndpoint)

            guard let url = NSURL(string: postEndpoint as String) else {
                print("Error: cannot create URL")
                return
            }
            let urlRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url)


            let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
            let session = NSURLSession(configuration: config)

            let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(urlRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
                guard let responseData = data else {
                    print("Error: did not receive data")
                    return
                }
                guard error == nil else {
                    print("error calling GET on /posts/1")
                    print(error)
                    return
                }
                // parse the result as JSON, since that's what the API provides
                let post: NSDictionary
                do {
                    post = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(responseData,
                        options: []) as! NSDictionary
                } catch  {
                    print("error trying to convert data to JSON")
                    return
                }
                // now we have the post, let's just print it to prove we can access it
               // print("The post is: " + post.description)

                // the post object is a dictionary
                // so we just access the title using the "title" key
                // so check for a title and print it if we have one

                if let durum = post["success"] as? String {
                    print("Success : " + durum)
                }


                if let postTitle = post["message"] as? String {
                    print("Message : " + postTitle)
                }

            })
            task.resume()
```

I want to achieve something like this:

```
func post(params : Dictionary<String, String>, url : String) {
.... code is here
}
```

and return the following:

> durum and postTitle with strings.

Thank you.

Comment: @ have any idea ? im trying but idont find solution i think need completionHandler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Asynchronous methods, its better to use completion closure if you want to return the result.

```
    typealias Response = (durum: String, postTitle: String)
    typealias Completion = ((Response?, ErrorType?) -> Void)?
    func post(params : Dictionary<String, String>, url : String, completion:Completion) {
            //.... code is here
           completion?((durum, postTitle), nil)
    }
```